# Unmaking a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

If I had a nested list:

```
Nes = [[2, 2], [4, 4], [8, 8], [16, 16]]
```

Would there any possible way to "unnest" it by making all the brackets inside the list go away so that Nes now looks like:

```
Nes = [2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
Nes = [[2, 2], [4, 4], [8, 8], [16, 16]]
print([i for sublist in Nes for i in sublist])
```

This outputs:

```
[2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16]
```

Please refer to the official documentation on [Nested List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) for details.

Comment: I have never used list comprehension before. Can you explain what that line of code does.

Comment: Flag these answers as duplicates instead of answering them in the future.

Comment: @J.Doe I've edited my answer with a reference.

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain

Nes = [[2, 2], [4, 4], [8, 8], [16, 16]]

list(chain.from_iterable(Nes))
```

output:

```
[2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16]
```